# How to parse a json object - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a json object like this:

```
{"1": {"penalty_percent": 3, "free_day": 5, "free_hours": 24}, "2": {"penalty_percent": 2, "free_day": 5, "free_hours": 12}, "3": {"penalty_percent": 2, "free_day": 2, "free_hours": 36}, "4": {"penalty_percent": 3, "free_day": 3, "free_hours": 48}, "5": {"penalty_percent": 5, "free_day": 2, "free_hours": 1}, "18": {"penalty_percent": 5, "free_day": 2}, "30": {"penalty_percent": 5, "free_day": 5, "free_hours": 10}}
```

I want to get `free_day` value from key object is `2`. (at this here is `5`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `JSON_EXTRACT`:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(json, '$."2"'), "$.free_day")
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that because you are using numbers as JSON keys, they need to be escaped in double quotes.

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Use Mysql `JSON_EXTRACT`, the alias operator is `->`,

Do something like this:

```sql
SELECT your_json_column->"$.\"2\".free_day"
FROM your_table
WHERE id = 1
```

More details: [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-keys)